# Property Mapping with Reflection efficiency

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have an object that I am populating via mapping and lookup woth Reflection, here is the call

```
this.SearchResults = (from a in response.postings
                              select new SearchResponseModel
                              {
                                  Id = a.id,
                                  TimeStampDate = a.timestampDate,
                                  Body = a.body,
                                  Title = a.heading,
                                  Status = a.status,
                                  State = a.state,
                                  Language = a.language,
                                  Currency = a.currency,
                                  CategoryGroup = a.category_group,
                                  Source = a.source,
                                  ExternalId = a.external_id,
                                  ExternalUrl = a.external_url,
                                  Price = a.price,
                                  Location = PopulateLocation(a.location)
                              }
                              ).ToList();
```

And the method that does the mapping.

```
 private static List<LocationLookupModel> PopulateLocation(Location location)
    {
        List<LocationLookupModel> allLocations = new List<LocationLookupModel>();
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["LocationModel"] == null)
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Session["LocationModel"] = allLocations = new LocationModel().LocationList;
        }
        else
        {
            allLocations = (List<LocationLookupModel>)HttpContext.Current.Session["LocationModel"];
        }
        List<LocationLookupModel> modelList = new List<LocationLookupModel>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in location.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(location);
            if (value != null)
            {
                LocationLookupModel model = (from a in allLocations
                                             where a.Code == propertyInfo.GetValue(location).ToString()
                                             select a).FirstOrDefault();
                if (model != null)
                {
                    modelList.Add(model);
                }
            }
        }

        return modelList;
    }
}
```

The issue that I run into is that allLocations object has about 70k records (it represents a list of location lookup values for countries, states, zipcodes, etc), and populating about 100 instances of SearchResponseModel takes about 20 seconds. This is far too long for a UI call, and I have not been able to find a way to make it faster. I understand I am basically doing 3 nested loops (calling helper method for each population, looping over reflected properties, and finally the LINQ call over 70k records) so there are some time efficiency issues, but I am a bit lost on what tricks I can use to make this process more efficient.

Comment: EmitMapper and FastMember.  They end up taking a ton of the performance pain out of the equation when mapping over repeatedly seen types. That said, perhaps this question is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DavidL I considered puttiing up on codereview, but went this route because I was hoping to get opinions on 3rd party tools which I have had good experience getting here. I will check those tools out, thanks!

Comment: While I understand your need, that does flag it as a close candidate :).  Good luck with the tools!

Comment: Are you asking for recommendations for third-party libraries to address this need? If so, your question is off-topic. Are you asking for help improving the performance of your own implementation? If so, your question would be on-topic, except that you haven't provided [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem you're trying to solve. Please figure out what kind of question you want to ask, and if you mean it to be on-topic here, improve it so that it is.

Comment: Tools would definitely help, that said your code is inefficient in many ways, so it could get much better anyway with no more stuff in the mix. For example, one basic issue you have, at each call you do `List<LocationLookupModel> allLocations = new List<LocationLookupModel>();` just before assigning `allLocations` to something else anyway, so you are `new`-ing garbage at each iteration. My advice, before going to blindly get *tools*, try to understand how you can do your best first. It's not just *tricks* as you call them, most of it is very basic stuff you should try to understand.